# ADFS + IdentityServer3 + Mobile + MVC

Tags: adfs, identityserver3, thinktecture

I am building a prototype with the following context.

- Two client applications (MVC & Mobile)
- IdentityServer3 as a relying party
- ADFS 3.0 as a identity provider
- IdentityServer3.WsFederation plugin to provide SAML support

The MVC side is complete, but I am not sure how to approach the mobile side.

My previous attempt used a Web API and ADFS' "adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed" endpoint. This allowed the mobile device to send credentials to the API which then authenticated the user using ADFS's endpoint. Then it returned a JWT token to the mobile app.

We must receive SAML tokens from the Idp (could be ADFS or a different Idp), but our apps are agnostic about the type of token.

I have two question.

1. IdentityServer3 doesn't support ws trust using the above endpoint (as far as I know), so what is the correct approach for this scenario for a mobile device login?
2. Is the WsFederation plugin needed since IdentityServer3 might handle converting the SAML token to JWT for the client apps.

Comment: How are you agnostic if you require SAML tokens?

Comment: We can use either a JWT or SAML token.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I wouldn't recommend SAML for Mobile devices (specially native apps) as SAML assumes clients as browsers. In mobile apps, it opens a browser to authenticate which is not the best approach i feel. I would suggest using OpenID/Oauth for mobile devices.

An Idp can support multiple Sign-In protocols such as  WS -Fed, SAML 2.0 or OAuth. It depends on the client to use the relevant protocol.

Coming to WS - Fed with IdentityServer3, There is an OWIN Middleware which helps in achieving it.

```
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation;

      app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                        {
                            Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44309/core",   //identityserver3
                            Wreply = "replyaddress",
                            MetadataAddress = "https://localhost/federationmetadata.xml",
                            AuthenticationType = "adfs",
                            Caption = "ADFS",
                            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "sometype"
                        });
```

The above code takes you to ADFS login screen, after succesful authentication you will redirect back to `Wreply` address mentioned above, It retuns SAML 1.1 response. You need to parse it and use it.